# install highcharts exporting server

Tags: maven, highcharts

I'm trying to install highcharts exporting server(by java). I want to write below maven command line in build.xml file of my project. Not run from cmd.

$ cd highcharts-export/

$ mvn install

How should I do that in build.xml file?

I wrote following in build.xml file and run by ANT. But nothing happens. And idea?

```
<target name="buildHighchartsExporting" description="Builds highcharts exporting">
<exec dir="${basedir}/highcharts-export" executable="cmd">
    <arg value="mvn" />
    <arg line="-f highcharts-export/pom.xml install" />
</exec>
```

```
<target name="buildWarFile" description="Builds highcharts exporting War">
<exec dir="${basedir}/highcharts-export/highcharts-export-web" executable="cmd">
    <arg value="mvn" />
    <arg line="clean package" />
</exec>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just trying to execute a project where the `pom.xml` is at another folder, you can use the [`-f` parameter](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/running-sect-options.html):

> **6.1.6. Using a Custom POM or Custom Settings File**
>   If you don’t like the `pom.xml` file name, the location of your user-specific Maven
>   settings, or the default location of your global settings file, you
>   can customize any of these things with the following options:
>   
>   **`-f`**, **`--file <file>`**
>   
>    Forces the use of an alternate POM file

This way, from where you'd execute:

```
$ cd highcharts-export/
$ mvn install
```

You can just use:

```
$ mvn -f highcharts-export/pom.xml install
```

### Running `mvn` from an ANT `build.xml` file

You can use the **[Ant Exec Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html)**:

```xml
<target name="buildProject" description="Builds the project">
    <exec dir="${source.dir}\${projectName}" executable="cmd">
        <arg value="mvn" />
        <arg line="-f highcharts-export/pom.xml install" />
    </exec>
</target>
```

Or, more specifically (to your example):

```xml
<target name="buildWarFile" description="Builds highcharts exporting War">
<exec dir="${basedir}/highcharts-export" executable="cmd">
    <arg value="mvn" />
    <arg line="clean package" />
</exec>
```

Comment: thanks, but my question is how to write "mvn" command line in xml file?

Comment: Aw, you want to run maven from an ANT file?!

Comment: I added an example of an ANT task to the answer. Check it out.

Comment: Thanks acdcjunior! Can you see my code above and anything wrong with it? Ant build does not do anything for it.

Comment: check the last snippet added to my answer

Comment: I dont understand, the code is same as what I have. But the build file does not working

Comment: Does ant give any error message? The `mvn` executable is in the `PATH` system variable? If not (or you don't know what I meant) in what folder is maven?

Comment: no error msg. I installed maven in my local desktop, but it is not installed in my project. So I guess thats the reason

Comment: What is the path for maven?

Comment: like this: C:\Users\..\apache-maven-2.2.1

Comment: If you go in `C:>`  and type `mvn -version` does it show anything?

Comment: How did this go, did you fix it?

Comment: nope actually we switch to not using this.. But thanks anyway!